# "event not found" trying to export a string with !0

Tags: bash

When I try to use `export password="abcd!0"`, the base gave me an error:  `!0: event not found`

Any help to solve this?

Comment: Use single quote: `password='abcd!1'`

Comment: `!` pulls up bash history, in your case, command #2 in that history

Comment: If you don't use the feature this represents -- turn off history expansion, as by putting `set +H` in your `.bashrc`. With modern GNU `readline`, it's very rarely useful.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`!` is a special character to bash
 it is used to refer to previous commands; eg,

```
!rm
```

will recall and execute the last command that began with the string "rm"

Try:

```
export password="abcd\!1"
```

or

```
 export password='abcd!1'
```

Comment: You might also suggest `set +H` in one's `~/.bashrc` to turn this off, making strings starting with `!` behave the same between the interactive command line and scripts.